# index out of range in a recursive call

Tags: python, function, recursion

I´m getting index out of range when I try to call my function more than once. I´m new to programming and cant figure out why or how to solve it.
the code works fine when:

```
if n == 9:
    return strng
```

here is my code:

```
def swap(n, strng): # helper
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(strng)):
        s += strng[i-n]
    return s

def encode(n, strng):
    temp_lst = []
    result = ""
    space_idx = [i for i in range(len(strng)) if strng[i] == " "]
    if n == 8: # works when 9
        return strng
    
    temp_lst.extend(encode(n-1, swap(n, "".join(strng.split()))))
    for insert_idx in space_idx:
       temp_lst.insert(insert_idx, " ")
    for i in "".join(temp_lst).split():
        result +=  encode(n-1, swap(n % len(i), i))
        result += " "
    return result


 
print(encode(10, "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."))
```

thanks in advance, and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to understand if you stated what you expected it to do. "encode" isn't a very explicit name; what are you encoding?

Comment: but the main question remains. why does it get out of range in `result +=  encode(n-1, swap(n % len(i), i))` ?

Comment: Please copy the stack trace with the exact error message; additionally, add the line `print('n: {}, i: [{}]'.format(n, i))` just before `result +=  encode(n-1, swap(n % len(i), i))` so you can see the values of `n` and `i` that make it crash.

Comment: I´ve noticed something, the code never execute when I put `n < 9` in my if statement and the first recursive call finishes with all the calls until it escapes, but I whant to make the recursive calls in order. what could be wrong?

Comment: "I will not tell you what I want my code to do but it is currently not doing it correctly. I won't show you the error message. I won't follow your advice of using `print` statements to figure out what is happening. What could be wrong?" is what I'm reading from you so far. Good luck.

Comment: the risk is that you will find a solution of you own and present it to me, its extremly important, that the solution is from me so I learn something. the code works fine and each step is correct, but when I increase the user input n, it stops and do the second recursive call. the `print` shows that the first recursive call go trough the whole string and shift it by 10 to right and the second shift each substring(space seperated to right). but the second dont execute with n < 9.

Comment: let me know if you whant to see the output so I can edit my question with an outout.

Comment: can you please copy my code and print the result so I can explain, use ur code snippet right before `result +=  encode(n-1, swap(n % len(i), i))` try first with `if n == 9` you will see the correct result, I whant that to happend, in that order if I call `n== 0`, but you can try that you will se that only the first recursive call is executing correctly.